# Worksheet.cells works, worksheet.range fails when workbook is not active

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

In Excel 2010, I have the following bit of code

```
Private Sub PrintCustExpHeaders(ByRef Report As Worksheet, ByRef StartRow As Integer, ByVal ClinicList As ProcessClinic, ByVal CES As CareExpSettings)

  With Report.Cells(StartRow, CES.CEClinicCol)
    .Value = "Title"
    .Font.Size = 18
  End With
  Report.Range(Cells(StartRow, CES.CEFirstCol), Cells(StartRow, CES.CELastCol)).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenterAcrossSelection
```

It executes just fine if I'm testing this snippet of code, but when I'm testing the full process, a *different* workbook is active when it gets to this `Sub` (`Report.copy` into a new workbook leaves the new workbook visible, I do  *not* execute `newWB.Activate`).

When the `NewWB` is active, it will execute `Report.Cells()` just fine and assign the value, but `Report.Range()` gives this error:

> Run-time error '1004':
> Method 'Range' of object '_Worksheet' failed

If I activate the original WB (either through `OrigWB.Activate` or by hand), the `Report.Range()` line will execute with no error.

It was my understanding that the whole point of declaring Workbook & Worksheet variables was so they could be referenced anywhere in code without having to use `.Activate` and `.Select`, so why is this failing when I don't do so?

Comment: All Range Object must have proper parentage assigned `Report.Range(Report.Cells(StartRo...`  So infront of the Cells put Report, even if they are inside a Range object that has it assigned.

Comment: Oh, jeez. I knew that.  :/  Make it an answer and I'll give you your 15 points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All Range Object must have proper parentage assigned.

```
Report.Range(Report.Cells(StartRow, CES.CEFirstCol), Report.Cells(StartRow, CES.CELastCol)).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenterAcrossSelection
```

So in front of the `Cells(...` put your sheet variable`Report`, even if they are inside a Range object that has it assigned.

An easier way is to use the With Block:

```
With Report
    .Range(.Cells(StartRow, CES.CEFirstCol), .Cells(StartRow, CES.CELastCol)).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenterAcrossSelection
End With
```